# Controller/route conventions for nested routes in ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, url-routing, ember-cli

I have this resource with a nested route in my ember app:

**router.js:**

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('posts', function () {
    this.route('show',  {path: '/:id'});
  });
});
```

What is the convention in ember for my controllers? Do I create a separate file for each URL, or does the `show` handler go in `/controllers/posts.js`? Or is there perhaps multiple correct ways of doing this?

This is what I have so far in **/routes/posts.js:**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

var PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return posts;
  }
});

var posts = [
  {
    id: '1',
    title: 'Object nr one',
    content: 'This is the content of Object nr one.'
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    title: 'Obelix',
    content: 'A fat gaul. From a comic book.'
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    title: 'Werner',
    content: 'Wat soek werner hier? Dis mos nou belaglik man.'
  }
];

export default PostsRoute;
```

And this is **/controllers/posts.js:**

```
import Ember from "ember";

export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({});
```

I would appreciate if someone showed me the correct way of doing things in this example.. I'm really struggling to find proper examples on the web.

*Please note that I'm using ember CLI*

Comment: You should create show route in routes/posts/show.js

Comment: Then what should the index route be? routes/posts/index.js? Or still routes/posts.js? @blessenm

Comment: It will be routes/posts/index.js https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.15.0/tutorial/subroutes/

Answer (score 1):

"Show handler" never goes to controller file, it's rather a `Route`. You create separate route, controller, template for each of your `resource` or `route` directives. You can tell controller that it should have the same behaviour as other controller, or use a mixin. For example:

router.coffee:

```
@resource 'training', ->
      @route 'chest'
      @route 'shoulders'
```

Means you need following structure:

> app/routes/training[your parent resource]/chest.js[your child route]
>   app/routes/training/shoulders.js

If you need controller for each of this routes you would need files with following paths:

> app/controllers/training/chest.js
>   app/controllers/training/shoulders.js

And templates:

> app/templates/training/chest.js
>   app/templates/training/shoulders.js

It's because I've defined `training` as resource(parent) and routes as its children.

If you use Ember CLI you can use commands like:

> ember g controller training/shoulders

or:

> ember g route training/shoulders

Last command will generate you: Route, template and entry in router.js. You can use this commands so you won't have worry too much about your directory structure.
However, it's **important** to remember that when you define resource inside a resource - child resource isn't really a child and it shouldn't be placed inside parent resource directory. For example:

```
@resource 'tracks', ->
  @resource 'track', path: '/track/:track_id', ->
    @route 'edit'
```

Means you need 2 directories to store route files:

> 1. app/routes/tracks/
>
>    - index.js
> 2. app/routes/track/
>
>    - edit.js

Instead of <del>app/routes/tracks/track/edit</del>.
So, in your example, for following router:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('posts', function () {
    this.route('show',  {path: '/:id'});
  });
});
```

app/routes should look like this:

```
app/routes:
 - posts.js # main route for whole resource
 - posts/ # directory which contains files for routes inside posts resource
   - show.js # posts/show route
```